# Setting the same variable multiple times is not working

Tags: python, api, datetime

Recently I have been working on a python program to return the number of cases for a certain date. The intended behavior is returning the correct active number of cases for the date inputted, however it instead returns nothing. Being relatively new to python I do not know what part of my code is causing this problem.

My code is listed below:

```py
import requests as r
import json
from datetime import datetime

#Code to return the day of the year of the first case in South Africa
data=json.loads(r.get('https://api.covid19api.com/country/south-africa?from=2020-03-01T00:00:00Z&to=2020-04-01T00:00:00Z').text)
data=data[20]
data=data['Date']
data=datetime.strptime(str(data),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').timetuple().tm_yday
print(data)

#This function is SUPPOSED to return the number of cases for the inputted day of the year. The the country input so far does nothing. On day 81 of 2020, there was the first case in South Africa. Therefore this function should at least retun 1.
def cases(day, country):
  ##Load the data from the API, this should encompass the whole year.
  data=json.loads(r.get('https://api.covid19api.com/country/south-africa?from=2020-01-01T00:00:00Z&to=2020-12-01T00:00:00Z').text)
  #Set some initial stuff.
  done=False
  i = 1
  cases=0
  while done == False:
    data=data[i]
    data=data['Date'] 
    #Get day of the year of the current case from the API.
    current = datetime.strptime(str(data),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').timetuple().tm_yday
    #Since the API orders cases earliest to latest this checks and increments the cases variable until it is no longer the current day.
    if current == day:
      cases += 1
    else: 
      done= True
    i+=1
  return (cases)

print(cases(81, 'south-africa'))

#2020-03-21T00:00:00Z
```

It seems that the shortest code to reproduce this problem is this:

```
def cases(day, country):
  data=json.loads(r.get('https://api.covid19api.com/country/south-africa?from=2020-01-01T00:00:00Z&to=2020-12-01T00:00:00Z').text)
  done=False
  i = 1
  cases=0
  while done == False:
    data=data[i]
    data=data['Date'] 
    current = datetime.strptime(str(data),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').timetuple().tm_yday
    if current == day:
      cases += 1
    else: 
      done= True
    i+=1
  return (cases)
```

Comment: Can you focus your title on the specific technical problem encountered? Ideally, if you could hardcode some minimal sample data in your program's text, that would ensure that the knowledge-base entry remains useful to others even after the API is no longer available (or if its version changes, or it's modified to require authentication, etc).

Comment: ...similarly, having some sample data showing the shape of the API's return values in the question itself would serve to make that question more self-contained, such that one doesn't need to go do an API call and read its response to determine either (1) how to write an answer, or (2) whether a preexisting answer one is thinking of voting on is actually correct.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: That said, first comment on reading the code: Reassigning `data` is generally a code smell. Use a different variable name when you extract something for easier readability. Thus, say, `current_item = data[i]; current_date = current_item['Date']` -- then when someone sees `str(current_date)` it's much more clear what you mean than if you wrote `str(data)`.

Comment: I would also suggest just getting rid of `i` altogether. `for current_item in data:` will do all the iterating for you.

Comment: Also, setting `done = True` the moment you see an item from the wrong day means you'll never find an item from the _right_ day, if it's not the very first thing in the list.

Comment: BTW, I would also strongly suggest rethinking this API design -- doing a new GET of the whole document every time you want to check just one day is going to be a lot of unnecessary load on the servers. Better to retrieve the data just once, cache it, and reuse it for however many queries you need to subsequently run.

Comment: Also, note that `cases += 1` means that your variable isn't counting _cases_ at all; it's just counting whether there was any data item for that country on that day at all. It would make more sense to use `cases += item['Confirmed']` or somesuch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reassigning `data` prevents this code from working, because when you start your `while` loop again and run `data = data[i]` the second time, `data` no longer contains all the results you got from the API, but now only contains a string with the data from the last day you processed.

Don't reassign variable names inside the same context.

```
def cases(day, country):
  ##Load the data from the API, this should encompass the whole year.
  data=json.loads(r.get('https://api.covid19api.com/country/south-africa?from=2020-01-01T00:00:00Z&to=2020-12-01T00:00:00Z').text)
  #Set some initial stuff.
  cases = 0
  for item in data:
    date = item['Date']
    #Get day of the year of the current case from the API.
    current = datetime.strptime(str(date),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').timetuple().tm_yday
    #Since the API orders cases earliest to latest this checks and increments the cases variable until it is no longer the current day.
    if current == day:
      return item['Confirmed']
  return 0
```